# Dynamically size javascript popup based on embedded swf size

Tags: javascript, flash, popup

I am embedding a swf in a popup window using javascript's window.open function.  I am currently passing in static values for the popup's height and width corresponding to the height and width of the embedded swf, like so:

window.open('http://whatever.swf', 'popup', 'width=400,height=300,resizable=1');

A user can click on a button in the swf, and it changes the size of the swf from 400x300, to 400x600.  Is there a way to dynamically resize the javascript popup window to account for this size increase without reloading the embedded swf?

Any help is much appreciated....

Comment: be aware that browsers do not guarantee resize will work without changing user settings. You'll want to test this across a range of browsers before relying on it.

Answer (score 2):

There is JavaScript's

```
window.resizeTo(x,y)
```

that you could call via the `externalInterface` from Flash.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping that `whatever.swf` in `whatever.htm` and put some javascript codes to resize the window, and call that from flash?